# How does Rails know which column from a table is the index in a related table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

The syntax for the `has_many`, `belongs_to` , etc. data schema modifiers don't require the specification of a column identifier to make the association.  *How does Rails infer the relations between tables?*  Examples I've seen all use the convention `<table_name>_id` in the tables that have an external relation: is this more than just a common practice?

Comment: The primary id of one table is taken as the link between two tables. Unless you specify that you cannot have a hook between two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like rails 'magic' but is just an assumption that ActiveRecord makes

> 4.1.2.6 :foreign_key
>
> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign
>   key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id
>   added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign
>   key directly:

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I thought as much.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails use "convention over configuration" pattern ([convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)). For `has_many` association, for example, there should be `foreign_key` (without it there is no way to understand how to link things), by default it is `model_name_id` column, but you can specify it (here info about [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)).

So you may have `Category` and `Article` models linked by `has_many` association, by default `active_record` will look for `category_id` column in `articles` table, but you may have `cat_id` column instead, and just write:

```
# in category model
has_many :articles, :class_name => 'Article', :foreign_key => "cat_id"
# in article model
belong_to :category, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => "cat_id"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation: I had to dig a bit through your answer for the answer to my question but I learned a few things on the way.